# How to extract number from a detected image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javacv, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I want to use opencv for extracting a number written of a speed sign. and since the detected sign will be just an image, how can i extract the number written on it?

how can I do that using opencv.

note: I know how to make image matching, but i do not know how to extract specific information "numbers" from the detected sign.

Comment: [Scene Text Detection and Recognition](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/text.html)

Comment: How about providing some sample images?